# Clojure.tools.logging always logs unnecessary stack trace info

Tags: logging, clojure, log4j

I've started to use clojure.tools.logging as this seems to be the standard wrapper around log4j. Independent of where I call it from, it does not log the call location properly -- instead, it always logs the same location, "clojure.tools.logging$eval667$fn__671"

```
Jul 23, 2014 1:44:54 AM clojure.tools.logging$eval667$fn__671 invoke
INFO [...]
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this? Thanks.

Edit: a very simple test code:

```
(ns test
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :as log]))
(defn -main
[& args]
  (log/info "Hello!"))
```

Produces the following:

```
Jul 23, 2014 2:09:55 AM clojure.tools.logging$eval457$fn__461 invoke
INFO: Hello!
```

Comment: You need to show a code snippet. Very little to go on here.

Comment: Ok, I added a snippet.

Comment: You may want to check out [Timbre](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/timbre), I found it works straight out of the box!